# acces from frame-timeline to class and from class to frame-timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I would like to store the value from combobox or text area-MovieClip in MyClass and then I'd like to read this from another frame in *.fla file only this :) have you another code? what can I write in frame 2 Miclass and frame 3

Comment: Try to explain your question better.

Comment: I have a combobox in frame 2 and I'd like to know the selected data when I go in frame 3                                                if ( stringcomboboxinframe2 == string1) {make somthing on frame3}                                                          else if ( stringcomboboxinframe2 == string2) {make somthing else on frame3}

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your combobox in Frame3 you can make a variable which contains it. Name your combobox "myCombobox" in instance properties. Though I don't know what combobox you are using so I name the class "Combobox":
  var combobox:Combobox = myCombobox;

So in Frame3 combobox will be removed from stage but you will still have a variable pointing to it.

Also you can check the value of combobox when you GO to Frame3 not when you are already there.

Comment: thank fro your answare valyard, but the first is, the combobox is in the frame 2. Must I make a class? and the second is that, in the frame 3 only I want to take a variable, So, if I make a class how can I store the value of mycombobox in frame 2 to class and how can I read the value of class to frame 3?